# How to remove rust and paint my barbecue?

Tags: repair, paint

I have a barbecue similar to the one in the image. It's still in good shape, but sun has taken out the shine and there are one or two spots or rust (really small) that would like to remove.

I would like to do something about it. Either polish it or paint it. Since the metal is subject to very hot temperatures I don't know if I can do it with any regular product or paint.

**How can I make the bbq shine again?**

[image: Barbecue]

Comment: The original coating is usually baked-on ceramic. It's probably not worth the time and expense to repair considering its fairly low replacement cost ($75-150 or so).

Comment: @isherwood agreed.  I don't apreciate throwing things away, specially if they are perfectly usable. But I should add that I will only do it if it's cost effective.

Comment: I don't think you can get the shine back but if you just want to protect the metal "stove black" spray paint can handle the heat.

Comment: @EdBeal yes, it doesn't need to look like it was just out of the box. But look a bit better. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Steel wool and a wire brush with a lot of elbow grease will get the rust off. Once cleaned you can apply a spray can of high heat black paint. The kind I find and buy doesn't have a gloss to it though so getting that shine might require a high heat enamel paint which I'm not aware of being in a spray can at my local stores.

Comment: Yeah, it's a "satin" finish.   I've used this before with good results, but it isn't "shiney":  http://www.homedepot.com/p/Rust-Oleum-Specialty-12-oz-Bar-B-Que-Black-Satin-High-Heat-Spray-Paint-7778830/202315061

Comment: What should I look at in the bottle? Does it say "high heat" or somethink like it?